# SSMS Database Mail not sending to multiple recipients anymore

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dbmail

We have a job in SSMS which runs daily and goes through steps that send out emails to employees with different reports. Recently, one of the queries stopped sending out emails and I'm not sure why.. I wasn't the one who made this query and I'm not an expert in SQL. One of the first things I tried was seeing if I could run it but take out the 4-5 recipients and only have one in there. To my surprise, it went through right away. I'm trying to figure out how come it might be slipping up when there's more than one recipient. Any ideas?

The query was working before, so I'm not sure how helpful it is to post.

**Here's the dbmail section:**

```
SET @BOD = '<HTML>
                <HEAD>
                    <H1>Company Name</H1>
                    <H2>Work Order Requirements</H2>
                </HEAD>
                <BODY>
                ' + @BOD

            SET @BOD = @BOD + '</table>'
            SET @BOD = @BOD + '</BODY></HTML>'

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                 @recipients = 'example@mail.com; example@mail.com; example@mail.com; example@mail.com;',
                 @profile_name = 'DBA_Notifications',
                 @subject = @SUB,
                 @body = @BOD,
                 @body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: So what happens when there are multiple recipients?

Comment: @Larnu It still tells me the query was 'executed successfully'.. but no emails get sent out. Bare with me, fairly new to SQL.

Comment: If they aren't sending, then you need to consult the error logs for the emails. What do the errors say when you run the following: `SELECT mel.description, mel.event_type, *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems mai JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log mel ON mai.mailitem_id = mel.mailitem_id
WHERE mai.mailitem_id = {Email ID};` (Obviously use the Mail Item ID for the email you said didn't get sent).

Comment: It looks to be related to your email provider. I suggest you to consult your email account in order to check if you didn't reach storage maximum or have any service blocked.

Comment: @Larnu Is that the same as checking in the current Database Mail logs under SQL Server Logs? I did find a few errors from the last time I tried to send it out.. it kept trying to go through but **"The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure... Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Command parameter... The server response was: 5.5.2 <example@mail>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address)."** It's taking out the ".com" from the address. Weird though, I just tried the same query and it went through to all the emails.

Comment: Sounds like what you *think* is being run, and what actually is, are 2 different thigns.

Comment: @Larnu I just don't understand the inconsistency there.. using the same exact query with different results lol.